# Why does MySQL's `explain` not say `filesort` when it's using `filesort`?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE condition = 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000;
```

`id` is the primary key. I have an index on `condition` and an index on `id` (I didn't add a composite index on `condition` and `id` yet). This query uses only the `condition` index, not the `id` index.

If I `explain` the query, it just says `Using where`. I expected it to say `filesort`. However, since this query is sorting without using an index, it must be using filesort. In addition, this query is timing out, which is another clue that it's using filesort. If I run the query without the `order by`, it doesn't time out.

Why does it sometimes not say `filesort`? I think it should be using `filesort` in both cases, since the query's so slow.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what your question is. MySQL needs to decide the execution plan **before** running the query. Whether the query is actually slow can only be determined later, when it eventually runs. And it's normal that different datasets produce different plans.

Comment: My question is that MySQL should be able to tell that filesort is needed for a query. If I run `explain`, it should be able to tell me. In this case, it can't tell that a query needs filesort, even though it's pretty obvious that it does.

Comment: How are you so sure it's using filesort? You're ordering by `id`. The table may already be in `id` order. Or it can easily order a list of integers in memory.

Comment: You mention a `status` index. Do you mean a `condition` index?

Comment: @Schwern Sorting in memory should still say "filesort". And yes, it should be `condition`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you're ordering by `id`. If the `id` is an auto incremented integer it's probable the table is already ordered by `id`. For example...

```
mysql> describe tablename;
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| value  | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| status | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> show indexes from tablename;
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tablename |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |      199824 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| tablename |          1 | value    |            1 | value       | A         |      101829 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| tablename |          1 | status   |            1 | status      | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from tablename where status = 1 order by id limit 1000;
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tablename | NULL       | ref  | status        | status | 5       | const | 99912 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

When ordering by `id`, no filesort. Watch what happens when we order by another indexed column...

```
mysql> explain select * from tablename where status = 1 order by value limit 1000;
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tablename | NULL       | ref  | status        | status | 5       | const | 99912 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

There's the filesort you're expecting.

---

In fact, `select ...` and `select ... order by id` both return in the same order. `order by id` is an implicit ordering.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE status = 1 order by id LIMIT 1000,10;
+------+-------+--------+
| id   | value | status |
+------+-------+--------+
| 1935 |    12 |      1 |
| 1939 |    59 |      1 |
| 1940 |    56 |      1 |
| 1941 |    21 |      1 |
| 1942 |     5 |      1 |
| 1943 |    68 |      1 |
| 1944 |    65 |      1 |
| 1947 |    27 |      1 |
| 1948 |    44 |      1 |
| 1950 |    75 |      1 |
+------+-------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE status = 1 LIMIT 1000,10;
+------+-------+--------+
| id   | value | status |
+------+-------+--------+
| 1935 |    12 |      1 |
| 1939 |    59 |      1 |
| 1940 |    56 |      1 |
| 1941 |    21 |      1 |
| 1942 |     5 |      1 |
| 1943 |    68 |      1 |
| 1944 |    65 |      1 |
| 1947 |    27 |      1 |
| 1948 |    44 |      1 |
| 1950 |    75 |      1 |
+------+-------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can't rely on this default ordering, but MySQL can.